# How do I return data from worksheet table as DataFrame?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, dataframe, openpyxl

After searching, I found a few things out but now I am stumped. In the worksheet it is a table with multiple incidents and I'm trying to get all closed and rejected incidents:

**EDITED**

```
def allIncidents(df):
    # creates a list of all Incidents
    pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["Queue"], values=["Status"], aggfunc='count').reset_index()

    ws = wb.active
    ws.title = 'All Incidents'

    pivot_length = pivot.shape

    len = pivot_length[0]
    i = 0
    while i < len:
        ws.cell(row=i + 1, column=1).value = pivot.values[i][0]
        ws.cell(row=i + 1, column=2).value = pivot.values[i][1]
        i = i + 1

    pie = PieChart()
    labels = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=len)
    data_val = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=2, max_row=len)
    pie.add_data(data_val, titles_from_data=True)
    pie.set_categories(labels)
    pie.title = "Incidents per Queue"

    # Use this to post on Graph sheet
    graphSheet.add_chart(pie, "B6")

def allClosedIncidents(df):
    # creates a list of all closed Incidents
    df = df.loc[(df['Status'] == 'CLOSED') & (df['Status'] == 'REJECTED')]
    # df = df.loc[(df['Status'].isin('CLOSED')) & (df['Status'].isin('CLOSED'))]

    pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["Queue"], values=["Status"], aggfunc='count').reset_index()


    ws = wb.active
    ws.title = 'All Closed Incidents'

    pivot_length = pivot.shape

    len = pivot_length[0]
    i = 0
    while i < len:
        ws.cell(row=i + 1, column=1).value = pivot.values[i][0]
        ws.cell(row=i + 1, column=2).value = pivot.values[i][1]
        i = i + 1

    pie = PieChart()
    labels = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=len)
    data_val = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=2, max_row=len)
    pie.add_data(data_val, titles_from_data=True)
    pie.set_categories(labels)
    pie.title = "Closed Incidents per Queue"

    # Use this to post on Graph sheet
    graphSheet.add_chart(pie, "I6")
```

**Error code**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/THABISO/PycharmProjects/Bancabc/BANCABC.py", line 276, in <module>
    allClosedIncidents()
  File "C:/Users/THABISO/PycharmProjects/Bancabc/BANCABC.py", line 79, in allClosedIncidents
    labels = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=len)
  File "C:\Users\THABISO\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\chart\reference.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.max_row = max_row
  File "C:\Users\THABISO\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 107, in __set__
    raise ValueError('Min value is {0}'.format(self.min))
ValueError: Min value is 1
```

The code is breaking at:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["Queue"], values=["Status"], aggfunc='count').reset_index()
```

The value of `len` in the first method is: 5

`len` in the second is: 0 (even though there are 100 closed and 20 rejected records

```
column names are: Queue,Client ID,Branch/Department,Category,Incident: Number,Staff,Description,Resolution,Opened Date,Due Date,Closed Date,Status,Compliant
```

Comment: Your error looks unrelated to the code you shared. There's no `labels = Reference(...)` line anywhere and we can't see your call to `allClosedIncidents()`. You need to take more care to ensure the correct code is being shared.

With the available info: it looks like something is going wrong with the parameters you gave to `Reference(...)` or perhaps the data its receiving has 0 rows or columns for whatever reason. It's unclear which.

Comment: @EricLeFort the code breaks at ```df = df.loc[(df['Status'] == 'CLOSED') & (df['Status'] == 'REJECTED')]``` when I use debugger and the reference was in an earlier called method that worked ```pie = PieChart()
    labels = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=len)
    data_val = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=2, max_row=len)
    pie.add_data(data_val, titles_from_data=True)
    pie.set_categories(labels)
    pie.title = "Incidents per Queue"```

Comment: @EricLeFort I edited it to add the rest

Comment: @ThabisoMotswagole can you please give us the shape of the pivot_table of the second method